# Python 3.8 printing variable name and value

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the name of a variable and its value. This is what I've tried:

```
a = 'oof'
b = 'foo'

def testprint(a):
    
    print(f'{a = }')
    

testprint(b)
```

but I get

`a = 'foo'`

but I'd like to print

`b = 'foo'`

Comment: You're printing a variable called `a`, not `b`. Values don't have a memory of what other variables they have been in.

Comment: if you want both name and value, maybe you need to look at data structure like dict. Otherwise trying to print the name you probably have something wrong with your design. Check https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Comment: `f'{a = }'` is syntactic sugar for `f'a = {a}'`, which is syntactic sugar for `"a = " + str(a)`. I don't know how you could expect there to be a `b` in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like that. Python remembers what value (object) is associated with a given variable (name), but not the other way around.  If you want to associate 'a' with 'oof' and 'b' with 'foo', you can do it like this.

```
dic = {'a':'oof', 'b':'foo'}

def testprint(var):
    print(f'{var} = {dic[var]}')

testprint('b')
#b = foo
```